# Custom setter not getting called in UIView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios5, getter-setter

I am using a custom setter for a bool property as I need to do some extra work when this value changes. Here is my implementation:

MyView.h

```
@interface MyView : UIView 

@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;

@end
```

MyView.m

```
@implementation MyView

@synthesize isSelected;

-(void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)_isSelected
{
    self.isSelected = _isSelected;

    //Custom code that changes UI based on bool state  


}

@end
```

However the setter is not getting called! Can someone tell me why?

Comment: How do you set the property when you expected your setter method to be called? More.... you can't set the property using dot notation in setter method.

Comment: In the same class, I go...
  isSelected = YES;

Comment: You should do `self.isSelected = YES ;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two ways to set your property and your setter method get called.

1、Dot Syntax : self.isSelected = YES ;
2、call it directly. [set setIsSelected:YES] ;

```
@interface MyView : UIView 
@property (nonatomic) BOOL isSelected;
@end

@implementation MyView
@synthesize isSelected;
-(void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)_isSelected
{
    isSelected = _isSelected;
    //Custom code that changes UI based on bool state  
}
@end
```

Your app crash because you call `self.isSelected = _isSelected` in your setter method, it will call your setter method recursively and endlessly until the stack over flow !

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it! I think I can ask this in the next iOS interview! :-)

Answer (score 1):

e.g. in viewDidLoad set value  `self.isSelected=YES;`, or where you want to set this value.

Your setter method should looks like:

```
-(void)setIsSelected:(BOOL)seleted
{
    _isSelected = seleted;

    //Custom code that changes UI based on bool state


}
```

This is "setter cycle" if you in setter use that code: `self.isSelected = _isSelected;`

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it! I think I can ask this in the next iOS interview! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `-(void)setIsSelected:` method's argument `_isSelected` to some other variable say `selected` and use it to assign the property as `_isSelected = selected;` in the method.

Comment: I did this. It causes the app to crash in the setter with EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
   //in myView.h
   @interface customView : UIView
  {

  }
  @property(nonatomic)BOOL *isSelected;
  @end
```

in myView.m file

```
    @implementation customView
    @synthesize isSelected = _isSelected;


    - (void)setIsSelected:(BOOL *)inSelected //inSelected is the in coming value for bool
    {
       _isSelected = inSelected;
       NSLog(@"setter is called");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, when your object is nil it will give you the sense that setter and getter are not called. Hopefully you solve the problem.

Comment: Aaron better put your answer. as a comment on the user's question.